# how to map in hibernate when a single table consist two list of diff entity

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have three class that is  A ,B and C
A to B one to many bidirectional relationship
A to C one to many bidirectional relationship

so A contain two list that is List and List
how to map this by using xml file .

the error I got is:

Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Stg_strategy.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: sorry list of A and list of B

Comment: As the error message is saying there's an error in Stg_strategy.hbm.xml it is hard to help you if you don't post more information, in particular the content of that file and the entire stacktrace of the exception